# How can i get nonvoters and voters from my mysql database with just the date of birth?

Tags: mysql, sql

!%[This is my databse.  I want a result with the full name of the resident and he/she is a voter.  Please help.  Thnx.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YG0sF.jpg)

Comment: Besides attaching a screen shot, rather than including actual text data, your screenshot is totally illegible.  Please add the relevant data to your question directly.

Comment: Question - how in the data would I tell for an example if a person is or is not a voter? Is that the purpose of the "residents.CmlStatus" column?

Comment: @RoboBear he wants to use `just the date of birth?`. Read the title!

Comment: @cdaiga - He might and not might mean exactly that. Respectfully, asking for clarification from the OP shouldn't be discouraged on SO.

Comment: @RoboBear, I think the `residents.CivilStatus` isn't a good property to use to test for eligibility. See [What does the term Civil Status mean?](https://www.quora.com/What-does-the-term-Civil-Status-mean)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming only those who are at least 18 years old are eligible to vote, do:

```
SELECT  ResidentId, 
CONCAT(IFNULL(FirstName, ''), ' ',
       IFNULL(SecondName, ''), ' ',
       IFNULL(lastName, '')) FullName,
       (Date(BirthDate)>=SUBDATE(NOW(),INTERVAL 18 YEAR)) VoterStatus
FROM Resident;
```

If the `VoterStatus=1`, that means this resident is eligible to vote, but if `VoterStatus=0`the resident isn't eligible.

Comment: I've tried your query and it gives the residentid and only the non voters.  Whtat i need is all the residents and there should be a new column with a record of voter or non voter. Thnx anyway.

Comment: That means there is no one in the resident table who is older than 18. To me the query looks good.

Comment: I just updated `(Date(BirthDate)>=SUBDATE(NOW(),INTERVAL 18 YEAR)) VoterStatus` to `(BirthDate>=SUBDATE(NOW(),INTERVAL 18 YEAR)) VoterStatus`, so try again.